# Naming of classes that may collide with java.lang.*

Tags: java, naming-conventions

Since `java.lang.*` classes are implicitly imported into every source file, this  makes it harder for a developer to use these class names in their own namespaces. For example, someone may want to create a `Compiler` class, since it is a common name and `java.lang.Compiler` is a rarely used. By doing so, the developer would have to use its fully qualified name, like `com.my.organization.my.very.long.package.name.Compiler`, every time, which does not improve code readability. Explicitly importing this class would be very confusing, and changing the name to something more specific is not always an option, because `Compiler` might be instead an interface for generic anything-to-anything compiler. Thus, in some cases the only option is to add a prefix or a suffix to distinguish the name. Another example I can imagine is a forum application, which may have classes like `Author`, `Post`, and yes - `Thread`. Adding anything to `Thread` would clearly distinguish it from functionally similar classes. Are there any conventions on class naming in such cases? The least intrusive option I personally see is adding a trailing underscore, like `Thread_`.

Comment: Ugly.  I'd rename the class to avoid the java.lang collision first.  Compiler is very generic.  You could make it more specific and clearer pretty easily.

Comment: I would name it, for example, `ForumThread` instead of `Thread`, or `JspCompiler` instead of `Compiler`. But this is really a matter of opinion. There is no widely accepted convention for this.

Comment: *"The least intrusive option I personally see is adding a trailing underscore, like `Thread_`."* That's not really a good idea. Too easy to misread, and the underscore tells you nothing of value.

Comment: @Jesper Well, if someone names it `ForumThread`, then he or she will have to do the same to other related classes, or the naming will be inconsistent. Imagine then, let's say, a dozen of classes with a totally redundant prefix, that had to be introduced because of a single class. Is this good for readability?

Comment: I agree with @T.J.Crowder that `Thread_` is not a good idea at all. How is someone supposed to understand the difference between `Thread` and `Thread_`? It would make the code quite obscure.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally been able to come up with names that avoided being so generic they conflicted, but even in those situations where you can't, provided your code is in a package, the unqualified name will be the package's class, not the `java.lang` one:

`stuff/Compiler.java`:

```
package stuff;

public class Compiler {
    public static long value = 42L;
}
```

`stuff/Foo.java`:

```
package stuff;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Compiler.value); // <== Compiler is stuff.Compiler
    }
}
```

Running that (`java stuff/Foo`) prints `42`.

Comment: Yes, it will, but as I stated in the question, this definitely will add confusion to anyone trying to understand the code.

Comment: @nbelikov: It's not all that uncommon (the JDK itself does it, not that I'm holding up the JDK as a model of API design excellence), but as I said, I try to avoid it. Frankly, even if I have to do some kind of cheesy prefix (`NCompiler` for a package called `nifty`, for instance), I'm usually okay with that. :-)